# Is there a time limit to campaign levels?

Tags: tropico-4

So far I've always managed to complete the objectives for the campaign levels, and I know there are various conditions that trigger a loss (losing an election, coup, having your palace destroyed).  But what happens if I just keep playing a level without either of these things happening?  Do I eventually run out of time to complete the level and have to start over from the beginning?

Comment: *successful* coup. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no time limit. [This guy](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2120026) seems to agree with my own testing.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of interesting information, but I haven't been able to find where it talks about time limits.  Can you help me locate it?

Comment: @bwarner "Since there is no time limit for most missions (at least in the beginning, where time limits would really hurt, later you can simply buy problems out of the way. There is only one mission where this doesn't work so well, I'll go into detail for that one)"

Comment: Ah, right at the beginning and I still missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: There is *one* caveat to this answer: The final mission in the normal campaign has, as its final goal, "Build [three very expensive vanity decorations] before 1970"... And missing the time limit is an automatic fail even if you didn't complete the previous objective until 1968.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the campaigns have time limits, since I've played one to 2013 before, which is past the limit for any sandbox game.